# How to use shift and modify-overwrite-beta in jolt

Tags: json, jolt

I want to know how to use shift and modify-overwrite-beta for the below input. Please **explain how it works** with your answer.

**Input:**

```json
[
  {
    "data": {
      "firstName": "Leanne",
      "lastName": "Graham",
      "id": 111
    }
  },
  {
    "data": {
      "firstName": "Ervin",
      "lastName": "Howell",
      "id": 222
    }
  }
]
```

**Desired output:**

```json
{
  "111": {
    "fullName": "Leanne Graham"
  },
  "222": {
    "fullName": "Ervin Howell"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can solve that in different ways.

**1. This spec is more understandable:**

1. Order your list with the `id` value as a key in the `shift` operation: `@(1,id)`
2. Concat `firstName` and `lastName` in the `modify-overwrite-beta` operation: `=concat(@(1,firstName),' ',@(1,lastName))`
3. Remove unused keys in the `remove` operation: `id, firstName, lastName`

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": { // index of the array: 1, 2
        "*": { // data object
          "*": "@(1,id).&" // value of id in the current object: 111, 222
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": { // ids: 111, 222
        "fullName": "=concat(@(1,firstName),' ',@(1,lastName))"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "remove",
    "spec": {
      "*": { // ids: 111, 222
        "id": "",
        "firstName": "",
        "lastName": ""
      }
    }
  }
]
```

**2. This spec is shorter:**

1. Concat `firstName` and `lastName` in the `modify-overwrite-beta` operation: `=concat(@(1,firstName),' ',@(1,lastName))`
2. Get the value of `id` as a key and put `fullname` in it: **key** `@(1,id).fullName`, **value** `@(0,fullName)`

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "fullName": "=concat(@(1,firstName),' ',@(1,lastName))"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "@(0,fullName)": "@(1,id).fullName"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

**The following image can help more:**

[image]

Comment: What's the meaning of `@(1,id)` in the `shift` operation?

Comment: When you want to use the value of a key, you can use `@` RHS in the jolt. for this one, it's mean of **`@(1)`**: get parent object and **`@(1,id)`**: get id from parent object.

Answer (score 0):

You can use those consecutive transformation specs

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {// represents the level of the outermost object
        "*": {// represents the level of the "data" object
          "*": "@1,id.&"//make "id" values key of each object, "&" replicates each attribute's values
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "FullName": "=concat(@(1,firstName),' ',@(1,lastName))"// concatenate attributes through adding 1 level deep shift of the tree as staying on the right hand side, and name by the literal "FullName" on the left hand side
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "remove",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "fi*Name|la*Name|id": "" //delete attributes "id" and the ones ending with "Names" except for the "fullName"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

as the names suggest **shift** is used to move the attributes/arrays/objects to their new places, and **modify** updates on the existing structure